# How do I extract element ID from loaded page

Tags: delphi, tembeddedwb

I have a project that loads some pages inside TembeddedWb. After the pages are loaded I want to grab the ID elements from some images. For example, I have an image like this inside  the html page

```
<a href="#" style="cursor:pointer"><img id="image1" src='pathto/image1' border="0" style="display:inline" /></a>
```

How should I read the ID element when I click on this image inside tembeddedwb?

I tried something like this:

```
 var
  MousePos: TPoint;
  HtmlElement: IHTMLElement;
  iHTMLDoc: IHtmlDocument2;
edit.Text := edit.text + ' ' + HtmlElement.id;
```

Do I have to use Tpoint? What should I do?

Comment: `IHTMLDocument2` interface has the [`elementFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method for this.

Comment: Please stop saying, "it doesn't work". Also describe how something fails.

Comment: already answered and it worked. 13 hours ago !

Comment: I offer advice for the future. If you carry on saying "it doesn't work" you'll not progress as much as you should.

Comment: you are right , Thank you for your advice and correction .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i follow TLama comment and i done it here is what i did for future help for others

```
var
  MousePos: TPoint;
  HtmlElement: IHTMLElement;
  iHTMLDoc: IHtmlDocument2;
begin
  MousePos := Ewb.ScreenToClient(MousePos);
  HtmlElement := iHTMLDoc.ElementFromPoint(MousePos.X, MousePos.Y);
  if Assigned(HtmlElement) then
    showmessage('id');
end;
```

Comment: This will work as long as the content of the browser is not scrollable and not scrolled somewhere. If so, you should add to your calculated client mouse position the scroll offset of the document as well.

Comment: Thanks Tlama  your comments helps me a lot